# ArcGIS Runtime: Adding WmsLayer using WmsService and WmsLayerInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis, wms

I am using ArcGIS Runtime 100.9 for WPF. I want to add a Wms layer to my map as follows, but it doesn't show up:

```
var _wmsUrl = new Uri(
"https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities");

var service = new WmsService(_wmsUrl);
await service.LoadAsync();

WmsLayer myWmsLayer = new WmsLayer(service.ServiceInfo.LayerInfos);
await myWmsLayer.LoadAsync(); // load the layer
myMap.OperationalLayers.Add(myWmsLayer); // add to the map
```

Suprisingly, if I change `service.ServiceInfo.LayerInfos` to `service.ServiceInfo.LayerInfos[0].LayerInfos` it will show up. I don't understand why. **Why I need to go to the sublayer, for the layer to show up?**

Comment: Take a look at section 7.2.4.6.3 of the [WMS Specification](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416): "*If, and only if, a layer has a <Name>, then it is a map layer that can be requested by using that Name in the
LAYERS parameter of a GetMap request.*". Often the top-level layer is not a named layer, but just a container for named child layers.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that WmsLayer API takes care of that. It feels awkard to manually fetch the leaves of the LayerInfos tree. If the layer tree of the WMS service is wide, I need to search for all leaves and then for every leaf define its own WmsLayer?

Comment: No idea how ArcGIS is supposed to deal with this, never used it. Maybe ask the developers. Note however that there is usually nothing like a "default" layer in a WMS. You (or the users of your application) have to decide which of the layers should be used.